# Mysql Workbench Connects with IP not with Hostname on Local Network

Tags: linux, mysql, local-area-network

Connecting to an Ubuntu machine from Win 7 over LAN using MYSQL Workbench.

Using hostname 'chili-xeon' fails to connect. I can ssh and ping using that hostname. I can also connect with Workbench using the remote machine's IPV4 address. The remote account user has its host set to '%'.

Any ideas about what avenues of investigation I could pursue to diagnose/fix the issue?

Comment: What is the error you got from MySQL Workbench?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a local DNS server and can you find chili-xeon in there? If not, you might need to add a static record in the DNS server pointing the name to an IP address...

Another way of doing this is by adding a new line in your hosts file:

```
w.x.y.z chili-xeon
```

Replace w.x.y.z with your server's IP